# Matched Pairs design definition

Tags: experiment-design, matching, definition

A horticulturist is planning a greenhouse experiment with 20 individually potted tomato plants to compare two fertilizer treatments. Ten plants are randomly assigned to fertilizer A, and the remaining are assigned to fertilizer B. Is this an example of matched pairs design?

Comment: As described, I don't think you have ten pairs. Seems you have two independent samples, each of size ten.// if you want ten pairs, then find ten different locations in the greenhouse and put two plants at each location, one with fertilizer A and one with B.  Pairing by location might be important if different parts of the greenhouse have different lighting, variations in temperature, etc.

Comment: How much variation do you expect between 2 tomato plants at grown in the same conditions?  In order to have a match pair test, you need to be guaranteed or have a reasonable assumption that the two samples behave the same under exactly the same conditions.  Good examples of match paired test are testing an person before and after taking a drug, Comparing the right and left tires of a car.

Answer (score 0):

Your design does not look like it have pairs, it has independent samples. The [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464740/matched-pairs-design-definition#comment859301_464740) by user "BruceET" have details.

A classic example of a paired design is the shoes example in the text by [Box, Hunter & Hunter](https://www.wiley.com/en-in/Statistics+for+Experimenters%3A+Design%2C+Innovation%2C+and+Discovery%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471718130). There, the goal is to compare two materials A, B for making soles. Each boy is given a pair of shoes with soles of materials A and B for the other.